# Fetch data from an external website on Android and display in a table - Get latest data

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, database

I am developing a simple app in android but am stuck. I am currently trying to grab the data from http://plan.regenbogen-gesamtschule.de/vertretung/schueler/subst_001.htm (This a school fixture plan)

I want to create an android app to display this data (Not Webview) and the data in the app should also be updated because the plan also updates in the web.

I think I have to create a database that updates the data automatically from http://plan.regenbogen-gesamtschule.de/vertretung/schueler/subst_001.htm and then I can use the data in the database to display it on Android. But I have no idea how to do it because I am a beginner, But this project is really important for me, so any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you are enjoying getting into Android development. Unfortunately you have two options.

1. Do it yourself with lots of time and trial and errors
2. Pay someone to do it for you

If you have to do it yourself, I suggest subscribing to Lynda.com to watch some great beginner videos on parsing JSON, changing Screens, Calling APIs and of course dealing with Recycler Views.

You will find it will be a struggle, but quite rewarding. When you think you are ready to give it a stab, here is a decent tutorial.

http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/

But keep in mind, I won't be able to write this for you nor would anyone else as it takes time and money to do it, so best of luck and I hope it turns out great. If you happen to roll into a fair amount of money and want someone to make it for you feel free to poke me ;).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so how I can contact you?

Comment: Hi Musayyab, My email is SRosewall@AppStudio35.com if you need something, but I do not have time to help you write an entire project from scratch as I take paid work only. However, if you have pointed questions that show you have done the research and lack a senior level understanding I'm happy to help or if you would like to hire me to build it for you I'm happy to help. Otherwise, I wish you good luck on your app and you have my email if you need quick help here and there.